# keep current CSS value in variable without changing

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to keep current CSS value of an element in a variable. My problem is whenever I change style of original element, the value in variable which I've assigned before changes too.

```js
var currentColor;

$("tr").hover(function () {
    currentColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    $(this).css("background-color", "#f7f7f7")
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", currentColor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr style="background-color:#FF0000"><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#00FF00"><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#0000FF"><td>Foo</td></tr>
</table>
```

I also tried to use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) but it didn't solve my problem.

```js
var currentColor;

$("tr").hover(function () {
    $("div").data("currentColor", $(this).css("background-color"));
    $(this).css("background-color", "#f7f7f7")
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", $("div").data("currentColor"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr style="background-color:#FF0000"><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#00FF00"><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#0000FF"><td>Foo</td></tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

Since community ask me why I haven't use `tr:hover {background:color}` I would have to include that in my actual project, and in that particular case I were into a situation that I had to modify back-ground color using jQuery. After that `tr:hover {background:color}` don't work and you have to manage `tr:hover` functionality with jQuery too.

I excluded that part from my question because I thought its not necessary to explain it.

Comment: out of my curiosity, why are you using jQuery to change the background colour on `hover`? in CSS it's just `tr:hover { background : #f7f7f7; }`

Comment: @fcalderan because once you use `$("tr").css("background-color", "some color")`, after that `tr:hover { background : #f7f7f7; }` don't work.

Comment: I would recommend you to learn HTML & CSS if you have just started  working in the front-end.

Comment: All I see from your code is that your rows have a background-colour that change when they are hovered. If there's nothing more and no specific reason to use js, then CSS is the way.

Comment: @shibualexis and what made you think I don't know `HTML & CSS`? Just because you don't see `element:hover {background:color}` in my code? Haven't you ever be in a situation that you had to change background-color using jQuery? In this case `element:hover {background:color}` stop working and you have to manage it with jQuery.

Comment: I am sorry if my comment offended you. Didn't mean to insult you. Since you have hard-coded the color #f7f7f7 in your mouseover event, I strongly believe it could be handled in CSS itself. In your case there is no need of JQuery or Javascript itself. I have also seen many recommending the same solution.

Comment: @fcalderan please read my update, write a sample code for yourself and modify background-color with jQuery. After that `element:hover` stop working.

Comment: @shibualexis no problem, maybe it was my fault and I had to explain more ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$("tr").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).attr("currentColor", $(this).css("background-color"));
  $(this).css("background-color", "#f7f7f7")
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", $(this).attr("currentColor"));
});
```

I don't know why you are using `$("div")` since you have no `div` in your HTML.

Second, use `mouseenter` and not `hover`

**jQuery Demo**

```js
$("tr").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).attr("currentColor", $(this).css("background-color")).css("background-color", "#f7f7f7")
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", $(this).attr("currentColor"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr style="background-color:#FF0000">
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#00FF00">
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#0000FF">
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Css Way demo**

```css
table tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style="background-color:#FF0000">
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#00FF00">
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#0000FF">
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz No problem happy to help

Comment: Why CSS demo? My question is clear `keep current CSS value in variable for later use`. I never asked `How can I do this with CSS?` :(

Comment: I added it to be nice, I never said you had to use it. Other might want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

**you can do it with PURE CSS**

```css
td:hover{
background-color:#f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style="background-color:#FF0000">
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#00FF00">
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#0000FF">
    <td>Foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Here you can find explain `:hover` in css:**https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: I know, but once you change background with jQuery for example using `$("tr").css("background-color", "some color")`, after that `tr:hover { background : #f7f7f7; }` don't work.

Comment: please specify what do you mean with "after that". Are you mixing css and javascript together?

Comment: @לבנימלכה please read my update. I am sorry because I didn't explain it earlier. I thought it is not necessary.